Delta-Epsilon proof of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x + 1}$
I've been trying to solve this problem with the delta epsilon proof, but I was unable to do so. I did the following:
First, I defined the bound for $\sin x$:
$|\sin x| \le 1$
Then, for $\frac{1}{|1+x|}$ using $0<|x|<\delta$. I get
$1 < |x+1|$ < $\delta + 1$. Then:
$\frac{1}{\delta + 1} < \frac{1}{|x+1|}<1$
Using the two bounds, I reach this inequality, however I was unable to continue
$\frac{|\sin x|}{\delta + 1} <\frac{|\sin x|}{|x+1|}<\sin x <1<\epsilon$
I don't know how to obtain the delta value or if there is a step I miss.

Use the bound $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$, instead.

$\frac{1}{|x+1|} < 1$ is not true when $-1<x\leq 0$, so it can't be a valid conclusion from $|x|<\delta$ no matter what $\delta$ is.

There are a few issues with your proof. First you need to pick a $\delta$ somehow dependent on $\epsilon$. Moreover it is not true that $\epsilon > 1$, it can be arbitrarily small. Lastly, it is not true that $1 < |x+1|$ (for example take $x = -0.5$).
The proper way to do it is to start by picking an arbitrary small $\epsilon$. Then try to bound your quantity in a way that will help you choose the $\delta$. Use the bound $|\sin{x}| \leq |x|$.

And I forgot to say that you need to also choose a $\delta$ that is not too large otherwise the denominator will give you problems. Try something like $\delta = min(\frac{\epsilon}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$.

@Esoog I'm a bit confused when trying to define a bound for $\frac{1}{|x+1|}$ shouldn't I start with the 0<|x|<$\delta$ given by the definition?

I got it, thanks you all. i didn't know the sinx inequality. nor what delta to asume.
